# Problems creating vector of threads in a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create different threads inside a loop and store them in a vector of threads.

**EDIT 1**: The number of threads is specified by the user.

```
const int numThreads = stoi(argv[3]);
```

**Initial code**:

```
vector<thread> vectorThreadsFFT{(unsigned long) (numThreads)};

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    vectorThreadsFFT.emplace_back(
            move(thread{FFT, ref(vectorBuffersUC), ref(vectorBuffersCD), ref(i), ref(numThreads)}));
}
```

**EDIT 2:** I'm joining the threads at the end.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    vectorThreadsFFT[i].join();
}
```

When I debug the code, I get segmentation fault (signal = SIGABRT). I've tried removing the move clause and changing `emplace_back()` by `push_back()`, but I still get the same results.

**EDIT 3:** It still crashes sometimes (but not everytime) when I create only one thread for this another function like:

```
thread th2{separator, ref(vectorBuffersUC), ref(numThreads), ref(nitems)};
```

Which header is as it follows:

```
void separator(vector<unique_ptr<lockedBufferUC>> &vectorBuffersUC, int numThreads, const long nitems){}
```

I'm starting to suspect that it is because of the parameters that I'm giving to the vector and how the function is receiving them.

Am I missing something about C++11 and thread management?

Feel free to ask for more details or code.

**SOLUTIONS TRIED:**

- Reserving space
- Passing reference of i by value

Comment: Does it work if you just create e.g. ten threads not in a vector? Just trying to isolate the problem.

Comment: @KennyOstrom No, I've just tried creating three threads and it aborts on the first one.

Comment: OK.  So this has nothing to do with "vector of threads", and is to do with "creating threads".  So *how* does it crash?  Does it run if you just call the thread function?

Comment: Also, `vector<thread> vectorThreadsFFT{(unsigned long) (numThreads)}` creates a vector with `numThreads` elements - all of which don't correspond to threads.  `emplace_back` (or `push_back`) then creates *another* element.  What you need is `vector<thread> vectorThreadsFFT;`, or if you really insist, `vector<thread> vectorThreadsFFT; vectorThreadsFFT.reserve(numThreads);`

Comment: Be careful with `{}` ctor format with vectors and other containers, it may do not what you expect.

Comment: So this crash has nothing to do with the vector, which might also be handled wrong based on all the other responses, but you never get that far.

Comment: Why are you constructing an object and passing it into `emplace_back`? You should let `emplace_back` do its job of constructing the object.

Comment: @Hurkyl Could you ellaborate a bit more on that? How would be the thread created without constructing it?

Comment: @danielsto: Because that's the whole reason for `emplace_back`'s existence -- you pass in the constructor parameters, and it invokes the constructor so as to construct the object in-place in the vector.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ok. Anyway, the `separator` function, stil crashes when passed to a thread, not to a vector of threads with `emplace_back()`.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.  This does not mean "copy paste all of your code"; it means work.  Copy your code and delete the parts you don't think matter, each time confirming that you still get the error, until your code is minimal and still produces the error in question.  All of your edits are symptoms of you not doing this to start.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not do what you are expecting it to do.

```
vector<thread> vectorThreadsFFT{(unsigned long) (numThreads)};
```

This correctly resizes the vector to hold `numThreads` elements. But, this kind of initialisation followed by `emplace_back` or `push_back` will add an element at `numThreads` index instead at `0` as you would expect.

One of the few correct things to do here would be to `reserve` the vector first and then do `emplace_back`.

Also, `move` is not required. With optimizations compiler is smart enough to do in place construction.

Another thing is, you must `join` the threads unless you are `detaching` it. `joinable` threads if not joined on destruction calls `std::terminate`.

```
const int numThreads = stoi(argv[3]);


vector<thread> vectorThreadsFFT;
vectorThreadsFFT.reserve(numThreads);

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    vectorThreadsFFT.emplace_back(
           std::thread {FFT, ref(vectorBuffersUC), ref(vectorBuffersCD), i, ref(numThreads)} );
}

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    vectorThreadsFFT.join();
}
```

Comment: I'm joining them at the end. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: I think you have forgotten array subscription.

`vectorThreadsFFT[i].join();`

Answer (score 2):

You pass reference to `i` to thread's closure, so it becomes invalid immediately after loops end. Try to pass `id` just by value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    vectorThreadsFFT.emplace_back(
        thread{FFT, ref(vectorBuffersUC), ref(vectorBuffersCD), i, ref(numThreads)});
}
```

Moreover, you shouldn't use `std::move` for rvalue object like `thread{}`.

And, as was mentioned by @Arunmu, you mustn't forget `join` all your threads before vector's destruction (it will cause `terminate`, see [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)).

Better solution is to use `std::async` to not to handle joining manually. Moreover, it will allow you to use lazy execution and better parallel scalable approach (see [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)).